# Python custom comparator for int type has maximum recursion error

Tags: python

```
# Recursion Error
class c(int):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self < other
```

```
# Working fine
class c(int):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return int(self) < int(other)
```

I intended to use the code this way:

```
a = [2, 1]
sorted(map(int, a), key = c)
```

I am still figuring out why type-conversion is needed for custom int comparator even though input parameter is int. It is probably a simple question but would love to learn more about how python works.

Comment: "even though input parameter is int" - this isn't so, and it's probably at the root of the confusion. Specifying `key = c` here means that `c(i)` is constructed for every element `i` of the input, and comparisons are done between those `c(i)`, not the `i`s themselves. So the inputs to `__lt__` aren't base integers, they're instances of `c`.

Comment: @slothrop Thank you for the response. Yes when I check the type its the c instance, but when I add integers and compare (even though its useless I just tested how type changed), it changed to instance of integer. Why does it happened? Does it mean adding instance of c and c is equal to its origin type of int?

Comment: You added integers, not instances of `c`. Such instances are created when you do your sorting, as you requested to compare the `c(your_integer)`. These instances never replaced the original int and appear nowhere outside of the comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The int type is not a class so calling `int(self)` produces an independent value which allows the inherently recursive comparison method to work.

By definition your `__lt__` method will produce an infinite recursion because the `<` operator will call the `__lt__` method of the object's class.

Normally you would avoid this by using super to reference the parent class'  method.

```
super().__lt__(self,other)
```

This doesn't work with `int` but you can call the type explicitly

```
int.__lt__(self,other)
```